# VMWare vmrun -T player start Ubuntu.vmx nogui fails (under Windows 7)

Tags: vmware-player

The VMWare player is running on Win 7 64.

The following command works fine:

```
vmrun.exe -T player start "C:\...\Ubuntu.vmx"
```

But when I try it with the nogui option then I get an error:

```
vmrun.exe -T player start "C:\...\Ubuntu.vmx" nogui

Error: Unknown error
```

The nogui option is supposed to work with VMWare Player?

Also, I would like to mention that I've suffered from another error but finaly found the solution at https://askubuntu.com/questions/342552/vmware-vix-vmrun-command-error-unable-to-connect-to-host-version-not-found (followed the instrucitons of @monstress, Aug 7 at 11:27)